# Not working, clickable div containing image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div containing an image clickable. I have tried all the techniques on [Hyperlinking an image using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117667/hyperlinking-an-image-using-css) (and acknowledge that it shouldn't really be done in css), and also looked elsewhere for any clues.

At first I thought it was because I hadn't set the size of the div to that of the image, but I still cannot get this to work.

Any ideas would be appreciated. the page where I'm trying this out is here: http://..., i.e., attempting to make the lighthouse graphic clickable (using any technique).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the `padding-left` for `margin-left` on the `div` with `id="pagetext"` in the `style` attribute, and  everything shall work.

```
<div id="pagetext" class="animated bounceInDown" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 25%; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
<div class="line"></div>
    <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: justify;"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: justify;"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: justify;"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: justify;"></p>
    <div class="line"></div></div>
```

Comment: Well, I don't know how I would have ever have figured that out!Thank you so much.  I'm still in the dark as to the 'why' if you feel like explaining?  Thanks again!

Comment: I just see that the `padding` is moving the `div` but  still keep the space for it, the `margin` is moving the `div` but free the space for other properties and setting. (Padding move but keep the layer on layer", Margin move but move with it the layer too). I hope the explaining is good :)

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaScript solution

Use an `onclick` attribute on `div`.

```
<div onclick='something()'>content</div>
```

and add `script` in JavaScript.

```
<script>
function something(){
  //code...
  //open other webpage:
  window.location = "http://example.com";
}
</script>
```